# How do I use Adobe CFC generator

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, coldfusionbuilder

I am using coldfusion builder to generate an ORM CFC. However, when I right click on the table in the RDS view and select "generate ORM CFC", I receive the following error message after choosing the location for the CFC:

"www.:8500.com could not be found. Please check the name and try again."

I have checked the server configuration and the RDS configuration. I have no clue what field this error is referring to.

I would appreciate any help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may like to use new Adobe CFC generator extension which can generate ORM CFC for you.
More can be found at-

http://blogs.adobe.com/coldfusion/2011/05/19/adobe-cfc-generator-coldfusion-builder-2-extension-available-on-riaforge/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a server for your project.

1. Right click your project
2. Choose Properties
3. Choose ColdFusion Server Settings
4. Choose a pre-defined server or add a new one

The server should point to the webroot of your site, so that the Adobe CFC generator files can be properly executed on the CF server.

A quick Google search for "setting up server in ColdFusion Builder" led me to this page:

http://www.mattgifford.co.uk/coldfusion-builder-server-management/

Once you get your server set up correctly (not just RDS, which is completely separate), then you should be good to go.

Dan